# The Inclusion Exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics

Q. How many bit strings of length $10$ either begin with $3$ $0$s or end with $2$ $0$s ?

My solution was that:

No. of bit strings of length $10$ starting with $3$ $0$s is $2^7= 128$.

No. of bit strings of length $10$ ending with $2$ $0$s is $2^8 = 256$.

No. of bit strings  of length $10$ starting with $3$ $0$s and ending with $2$ $0$s is $2^5=32$.

According to what I understood about the question is that to find the answer I must do this:
$$128+256-(2\times32)=320.$$
$2\times 32$ has been subtracted because we just need to find no. of bit strings either begin with $3$ $0$s or end with $2$ $0$s only so why should I subtract it only once!!
I wanted to ask what is the wrong part that I have understood??

Comment: You counted the strings of the form $000X00$ twice, once because they start with $000$ and again because they end in $00$.  You only wanted to count them once, so you have to subtract them once.

Comment: But subtracting it once, wouldn't it give me a set of nos. where I still have of the form 000X00 but do I need this set

Comment: Not following.  I assume that you do want to count strings of the form $000X00$, you just want to count them once, not twice.  If you don't want to count them at all, that's different.

Comment: Maybe things would be clearer if you worked out a smaller example.  Say, strings of length 4 starting with 00 or ending with 0.  List out all the examples on a bit of paper, and count, and reconcile with the kind of formulas you have been working with.

Comment: If you want to get clarity, suppose the strings are of length $5$.  Then you can list everything out.

Comment: According to the question it says that either of the form 000X or of the form X00. That is why I was having a doubt.

Comment: It seems to me that the confusion is in the phrase "**either** begin with... or end with..."  In some contexts people interpret *either... or* to mean the exclusive or in which case your answer where you subtract $2\times 32$ is correct, that is to say your answer is correct for the interpretation that we want exactly one of the conditions to be true.  If it was meant to have the *inclusive* or instead, where we allow both conditions to be true simultaneously and we want to include those cases in our count, then we should only have subtracted $32$ once, not twice.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the problem...just one last concern what would you have done if the same you face whether will you subtract it once or twice?

Comment: If you don't want to count strings of the form $000X00$ at all then you have to subtract the number of those strings twice.

Comment: Okay....thanks everyone for your help